# Factorization and probability of occurrence

Tags: prime-factorization

We are given a large random number $N$ of size $n>k$, is it possible to compute the probability of occurrence of a prime factor of size $k$?

For a prime $2$, we know that $P(2\ |\ N)=1/2$. What about a prime greater than $2$?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems reasonable to set $P(p|N)=1/p$ for  primes $2\le p<N/2$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a theoretic answer. [Here](https://www.random.org/) I got $10,000$ really random numbers between $2$ to $10^9$, (not pseudorandom) and I made this table.

In the first column there is a prime $p$ up to $1,000$, more or less. In the second the percentage of the $10,000$ random numbers divided by $p$ and in the third ther is simply $1/p$

Doesn't prove anything, but is quite interesting

$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
p & rel.frequency &theor.frequency=1/p\\
\hline
 2 & 0.5045 & 0.5000 \\
 31 & 0.0296 & 0.03226 \\
 73 & 0.0132 & 0.01370 \\
 127 & 0.0086 & 0.007874 \\
 179 & 0.0054 & 0.005587 \\
 233 & 0.004 & 0.004292 \\
 283 & 0.0024 & 0.003534 \\
 353 & 0.0035 & 0.002833 \\
 419 & 0.0018 & 0.002387 \\
 467 & 0.0021 & 0.002141 \\
 547 & 0.0021 & 0.001828 \\
 607 & 0.0017 & 0.001647 \\
 661 & 0.0012 & 0.001513 \\
 739 & 0.0012 & 0.001353 \\
 811 & 0.0011 & 0.001233 \\
 877 & 0.0008 & 0.001140 \\
 947 & 0.0007 & 0.001056 \\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives an idea.